# How do I use a iterator adapter with a function returning impl Trait as the IntoIter associated type of IntoIterator?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, lifetime

I have a struct with a `Vec<nalgebra::Vector3<f32>>`:

```
use nalgebra::Vector3;

struct VecOfVector {
    data: Vec<Vector3<f32>>,
}

fn float_iter_vector(vec: &mut Vector3<f32>) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut f32> {
    vec.iter_mut()
}
```

I need to implement `IntoIterator` for a mutable reference to this struct with the `Item` type being `&mut f32` (a.k.a., flatten into an iterator over `f32`). This can be done using `flatten` and `map`, but I am not sure how to specify the return type for the `map` part of the iterator.

From my understanding, each function has a unique type. Is there any way to access this specific type (a.k.a., the function returns a `Map` iterator using this exact function)?

```
use std::iter::{Flatten, Map};
use std::slice::IterMut;

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut VecOfVector {
    type Item = &'a mut f32;

    // how do I specify type of "float_iter_vector"?
    type IntoIter = Flatten<Map<IterMut<'a, f32>, float_iter_vector>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.data.iter_mut().map(float_iter_vector).flatten()
    }
}
```

I can solve this problem with boxing, but I am worried this will lead the iterator to not be inlined and it is used in performance sensitive code. Will LLVM still be able to inline it?

```
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut VecOfVector {
    type Item = &'a mut f32;

    type IntoIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Self::Item> + 'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Box::new(self.data.iter_mut().map(float_iter_vector).flatten())
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I would be happy to solve this problem using [the type_alias_impl_trait feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063), but this leads to a lifetime error I think is a compiler bug.

```
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut VecOfVector {
    type Item = &'a mut f32;

    // hidden type error (likely compiler bug?)
    type IntoIter = impl Iterator<Item = &'a mut f32> + 'a;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.data.iter_mut().map(float_iter_vector).flatten()
    }
}
```

I have all three versions of this code in a playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0850edff23378df08da6f4811d0c4b7d)

I also [posted this question on r/rust](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/fgdp1y/returning_map_as_intoiter_for_intoiterator/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [answered on r/rust by u/leo60228](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/fgdp1y/returning_map_as_intoiter_for_intoiterator/).

> You have to explicitly specify the nalgebra iterator type. This results in somewhat of a generic soup (like most things in nalgebra): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=715819c2b93592bae96f819bb020264f

```
use nalgebra::base::iter::MatrixIterMut;
use nalgebra::dimension::*;
use nalgebra::storage::Owned;
use nalgebra::Vector3;

struct VecOfVector {
    data: Vec<Vector3<f32>>,
}

fn float_iter_vector(vec: &mut Vector3<f32>) -> MatrixIterMut<f32, U3, U1, Owned<f32, U3, U1>> {
    vec.iter_mut()
}

type FloatIterVector =
    for<'a> fn(&'a mut Vector3<f32>) -> MatrixIterMut<'a, f32, U3, U1, Owned<f32, U3, U1>>;

use std::iter::{Flatten, Map};
use std::slice::IterMut;

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut VecOfVector {
    type Item = &'a mut f32;

    type IntoIter = Flatten<Map<IterMut<'a, Vector3<f32>>, FloatIterVector>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.data
            .iter_mut()
            .map(float_iter_vector as FloatIterVector)
            .flatten()
    }
}
```

Comment: So the answer is "don't use impl trait and write out all the explicit types"?

Comment: Yep, at least until impl trait lands on stable.